# If statement help on macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
  Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date, sTime As Date, eTime As Date
  sTime = Sheet2.[B3]
  eTime = Sheet2.[B4]
  
    
 If sTime > eTime Then
    Call pullInferred_Time(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B3], Sheet2.[B4], "Inferred_Time")
    Call pullPPR(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B3], Sheet2.[B4])
    Call pullPod_Gaps(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B8], Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])
    Call pullOOWA(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B8], Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])
    Call pullKiva_Scout(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B8], Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])
    
   Else
    Call pullInferred_Time(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B3], Sheet2.[B4], "Inferred_Time")
    Call pullPPR(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B3], Sheet2.[B4])
    Call pullPod_Gaps(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])
    Call pullOOWA(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])
    Call pullKiva_Scout(Sheet2.[B1], Sheet2.[B2], Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])


Sub pullPod_Gaps(sDate, eDate, sTime, eTime)
    Dim H As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim dataobj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim URL As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlMetricTotals As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTable As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTBody As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTR As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    
    i = 2
    
    'sDate = ConvertFromLocalTimezoneToUTC(sDate)
    'eDate = ConvertFromLocalTimezoneToUTC(eDate)
    
    'sDate = toUnix(sDate)
    'eDate = toUnix(eDate)
    
    URL = "https://roboscout.amazon.com/view_plot_data/?sites=(LGB3" _
& ")&current_day=false&startDateTime=" & Format(sDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
& Format(sTime, "+hh%3A") _
& Format(sTime, "nn%3A00") _
& "&endDateTime=" & Format(eDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
& Format(eTime, "+hh%3A") _
& Format(eTime, "nn%3A00") _
& "&mom_ids=1443&osm_ids=977&oxm_ids=1131&ofm_ids=602&viz=nvd3Table&instance_id=0&object_id=20990&BrowserTZ=America%2FLos_Angeles&app_name=RoboScout&mode=CSV"

    Debug.Print URL
    
    H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
    H.SetTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
    H.Open "GET", URL, False
    H.SetClientCertificate "CURRENT_USER\MY\" & Environ("USERNAME")
    H.setRequestHeader "Cookie", VBAMidway_v1()
    H.send
    H.WaitForResponse
    Debug.Print H.Status
    Debug.Print H.responseText
    
     dataobj.SetText H.responseText
    dataobj.PutInClipboard

    With Sheets("Pod_Gaps")
        .Activate
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
        .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False
    End With
    
End Sub


Sub pullOOWA(sDate, eDate, sTime, eTime)
    Dim H As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim dataobj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim URL As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlMetricTotals As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTable As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTBody As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTR As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    
    i = 2
    
    'sDate = ConvertFromLocalTimezoneToUTC(sDate)
    'eDate = ConvertFromLocalTimezoneToUTC(eDate)
    
    'sDate = toUnix(sDate)
    'eDate = toUnix(eDate)
    
    URL = "https://roboscout.amazon.com/view_plot_data/?sites=(LGB3" _
& ")&startDateTime=" & Format(sDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
& Format(sTime, "+hh%3A") _
& Format(sTime, "nn%3A00") _
& "&endDateTime=" & Format(eDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
& Format(eTime, "+hh%3A") _
& Format(eTime, "nn%3A00") _
& "&mom_ids=2170%2C2168&osm_ids=1426&oxm_ids=2593&ofm_ids=1017&instance_id=0&object_id=21628&BrowserTZ=America%2FLos_Angeles&app_name=RoboScout&mode=CSV"


    Debug.Print URL
    
     H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
    H.SetTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
    H.Open "GET", URL, False
    H.SetClientCertificate "CURRENT_USER\MY\" & Environ("USERNAME")
    H.setRequestHeader "Cookie", VBAMidway_v1()
    H.send
    H.WaitForResponse
    Debug.Print H.Status
    Debug.Print H.responseText
    
     dataobj.SetText H.responseText
    dataobj.PutInClipboard

    With Sheets("OOWA")
        .Activate
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
        .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False
    End With
    
End Sub


Sub pullKiva_Scout(sDate, eDate, sTime, eTime)
    Dim H As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim dataobj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim URL As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlMetricTotals As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTable As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTBody As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim htmlTR As HTMLHtmlElement
    Dim i As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    
    i = 2
    
    'sDate = ConvertFromLocalTimezoneToUTC(sDate)
    'eDate = ConvertFromLocalTimezoneToUTC(eDate)
    
    'sDate = toUnix(sDate)
    'eDate = toUnix(eDate)
    
    URL = "https://kivascout.amazon.com/view_plot_data/?sites=(LGB3" _
& ")&current_day=false&startDateTime=" & Format(sDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
& Format(sTime, "+hh%3A") _
& Format(sTime, "nn%3A") _
& "00&endDateTime=" _
& Format(eDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") _
& Format(eTime, "+hh%3A") _
& Format(eTime, "nn%3A") _
& "00&mom_ids=394%2C362%2C379%2C426&osm_ids=&oxm_ids=444&ofm_ids=&viz=nvd3Table&instance_id=1927&object_id=19851&BrowserTZ=America%2FLos_Angeles&app_name=RoboScout&mode=CSV"

    Debug.Print URL
    
    H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
    H.SetTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
    H.Open "GET", URL, False
    H.SetClientCertificate "CURRENT_USER\MY\" & Environ("USERNAME")
    H.setRequestHeader "Cookie", VBAMidway_v1()
    H.send
    H.WaitForResponse
    Debug.Print H.Status
    Debug.Print H.responseText
    
     dataobj.SetText H.responseText
    dataobj.PutInClipboard

    With Sheets("Kiva_Scout")
        .Activate
        .Cells.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
        .Columns("A:A").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Im kinda stuck here I need my code to be able to check to see if the value for  sheet2.[B5] is greater than the value for Sheet2.[B6] then it will use the value for Sheet2.[B8] instead of the value in Sheet2.[B2] but only for the following calls(OOWA, Pod_gaps, Kiva_scout). sorry if I didn't write this well I'm new to VBA

Comment: need more details, where are the subs for pullPod_Gaps, pullOOWA, pullKiva_Scout etc?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @earthguestg Ive included the subs for the following pullPod_Gaps, pullOOWA, pullKiva_Scout

Comment: @ObieOsuji just looked at it, I still don't understand the question clearly. Is the following what you want?
Call pullPod_Gaps(Sheet2.[B1], IIF(Sheet2.[B5].value>Sheet2.[B6].value,Sheet2.[B8],Sheet2.[B2]), Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6])

Comment: @earthguestg The macro runs on UTC time and after 3pm the end date switches to the next day I need the macro to compare the values in Sheet2.[B5], Sheet2.[B6] when the value for Sheet2.[B5] is greater than the value for sheet2.[B6], I need the macro to use the value on Sheet2.[B8] instead of the value in Sheet2.[B2] for the following calls(pullPod_Gaps, pullOOWA, pullKiva_Scout)as the end date which is why I was using an If statement. The values in B[5] and B[6] are automatically converted to UTC time depending on the values in B[3] and B[4] respectively.